# Using the same version of a type dependency of a dependency

Tags: typescript, npm, package.json

This is a question regarding external Typescript types or interfaces being used by a dependent package and how we should reference them.

---

Package `a` depends on package `b`.

Package `a` has something called `ThingA` (could be a function/a function parameter/an object etc.) that uses a Typescript type called `TypeB` that is exported by package `b`.

My code depends on package `a`. I want to use `TypeB` in my code that somehow interfaces with `ThingA`.

Two solutions with their issues:

1. My code also depends on package `b`: The problem here is that my code could be depending on an older or newer version of `b` than `a` and so the types can potentially not match if types changed between the 2 versions.
2. I use a [utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html). The problem here is that `ThingA` can be a convoluted function that has a parameter that is a function that has a parameter of type `TypeB`. Inferring this can look really unweildy, especially when compared to just writing `TypeB`.

Is there a way to directly use the **correct** version of `TypeB` in my code **without** using a utility type?